# макросы в Excel

Tags: алгоритм, excel, vba, activex

Как можно рассчитать время в Excel через макросы? Т.Е Имеется фактическое начало и фактическое окончание нужно высчитать сколько времени было затрачено. Но должно учитываться выходные и праздничные дни и рабочее время с 9:00 до 18:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот совсем простенький макрос для расчета числа рабочих часов в рабочие дни:

```
Sub time()
    Dim StartWork As Date
    Dim EndWork As Date
    Dim Msg

    StartWork = InputBox("Введите дату начала работ в формате дд/мм/гггг")
    EndWork = InputBox("Введите дату окончания работ в формате дд/мм/гггг")

    Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(StartWork, EndWork) * 9
    Msg = Msg & " рабочих часа(ов) в периоде" & vbNewLine
    Msg = Msg & "с " & StartWork & " по " & EndWork

    MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Описание функции  `NetworkDays` [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835532.aspx).

Если же необходимо учитывать еще и часы начала/окончания работ, то будет все чуточку сложнее.

Все то же самое (и быстрее) можно сделать без использования VBA обычными формулами:

```
=ЧИСТРАБДНИ.МЕЖД("22.09.2015";"28.09.2015")*9
```

- вычисляет кол-во рабочих дней в диапазоне дат и умножает на 9 часов;

```
=(ЧИСТРАБДНИ.МЕЖД("22.09.2015  12:00:00";"28.09.2015  15:00:00")-2)*9+18-ЧАС("22.09.2015  12:00:00")+18-ЧАС("28.09.2015  15:00:00")
```

- вычисляет кол-во рабочих дней в диапазоне без крайних двух дней, умножает на 9 часов; и отдельно вычисляет число часов в крайних двух днях;

Описание функции `ЧИСТРАБДНИ.МЕЖД` [здесь](https://support.office.com/ru-RU/article/%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%91%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%98-%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%96%D0%94-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%91%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%98-%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%96%D0%94-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28)

Довольно грубо и "в лоб", без проверки попадания времен в рабочий период... Но считает)

Comment: В принципе то что нужно, но вот есть одно но. этот макрос должен рассчитывать из выгруженного отчёта как это сделать?

Comment: Тогда вместо `=inputbox(...` поставить  `=Range("A1")` и `=Range("A2")`; вместо `A1` и `A2` подставить два адреса ячеек с датами начала и конца периода. **Важное замечание!** Активным листом при запуске макроса должен быть лист с этими датами, иначе необходимо будет прописать полный путь с названием книги и листа.

Comment: Здорова. А как из 2 столбцов в выдать информацию в 3 столбец? То есть если макрос посчитал в ячейке А1 и А2 и выдал результат в А3. И можно ли посчитать не по ячейкам а сразу целый столбец?

Comment: Эм, это можно сделать борльшим кол-вом способов...Например прогнать исполняемую формулу по циклу (кол-во пар дат в столбцах) и записывать результат в ячейку в третьем столбце. Но я плохо понимаю, зачем для этого использовать VBA, если можно просто написать формулу в третьем столбце...

Answer (score 0):

Для расчёта с помощью макросов нужно обратиться к языку VBA. В нём для этого есть функция [DateDiff](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-DateDiff-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU).

Comment: А можно поподробней?

Comment: если ячейки типа дата то можно вычислять как обычную разность не обязательно юзать макросы